# malloc error during Build inode method for Unixlike file system

Tags: c, unix

I am making unixlike file system as my university project and I am getting memory allocation error during making of file block with malloc method . Please help me. My code is as under :

```
char *BuildInode(int fileType)
{
    int size = 0;
    char *inode = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * SECTOR_SIZE_1/NUM_INODES_PER_BLOCK); 
    char *negativeOne = '\0';
    inode[5] = fileType + 4;
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < MAX_NUM_SECTORS_PER_FILE; index++)
    {
        inode[index + 2] = negativeOne;
    }
    return inode;
}
```

Comment: What are `SECTOR_SIZE_1`, `NUM_INODES_PER_BLOCK` and `MAX_NUM_SECTORS_PER_FILE` ?

Comment: And what exactly does this mean : _I am getting memory allocation error_? Does it show an error message? If yes which error message exactly?

Comment: `Dir_Create /usr/
Dir_Create returned 0
Dir_Create /usr/nextDir/
The dir /usr/nextDir/ has been created with result 0
FS_Create
File_Create returned -1
FS_Create
* Error in `./program': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x000000000216ec70 `

Comment: SECTOR_SIZE_1 = 512;NUM_INODE_BLOCKS = 250;

Comment: MAX_NUM_SECTORS_PER_FILE = 30;

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that SECTOR_SIZE_1 < NUM_INODES_PER_BLOCK and as a result (SECTOR_SIZE_1/NUM_INODES_PER_BLOCK is 0).

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, please get 50 reputation before commenting.

Comment: you can see my values i have provided previously.

Answer (score 0):

if `SECTOR_SIZE_1 = 512` and `NUM_INODE_BLOCKS = 250` then `SECTOR_SIZE_1/NUM_INODES_PER_BLOCK` is, guess what, `2`,

Therefore the argument to malloc (`sizeof(char) * SECTOR_SIZE_1/NUM_INODES_PER_BLOCK`) is also 2, so you allocate a buffer of exactly 2 bytes.

Then in the for loop you fill this buffer to a size of `MAX_NUM_SECTORS_PER_FILE + 2 = 32`, or in other words you write 30 bytes beyond the end of the buffer.

A typical case of buffer overflow and subsequent undefined behaviour (an error message in your case).

Comment: So what should I need to do ?Do I need to reduce the MAX_NUM_SECTORS_PER_FILE?

Comment: @ApurvaBhavsar I don't know your requirements, all I can tell you is "dont write beyond the end of allocated memory".

Comment: @ApurvaBhavsar ... or in other words: allocate sufficient memory so your buffer is large enough to contain the data you're writing into it.